# код телеграмм бота не работает, но не знаю в чем вопрос

Tags: python, telebot

Имеется такой код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def get_filial(message):

    markup_inline_branch=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_tokio=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Tokio', callback_data='tokio')
    item_texas=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Texas', callback_data='texas')


    markup_inline_filial.add(item_tokio, item_texas, )

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,text="Choose branch :",reply_markup=markup_inline_branch)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def get_items(call):
if call.data=='tokio':
    markup_inline_item=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_category=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Choose category', callback_data='category')
    item_warehouse=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Choose warehouse', 
    callback_data='warehouse')

  
    markup_inline_item.add(item_category, item_warehouse, item_folder)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,text="Choose 
    category:",reply_markup=markup_inline_item)
```

Но это часть кода не запускается, не понимаю в чем проблема.
Подскажите где исправить.
Спасибо.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def get_category(call):
    if call.data=='category':
    markup_inline_goods=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_milk=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Milk', callback_data='milk')
    item_electrocity=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Electrocity', callback_data='electr')
 
    markup_inline_goods.add(item_milk, item_eleсtr,)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,text="Choose 
    goods:",reply_markup=markup_inline_goods)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD.
У меня всё работает.

```
from telebot import TeleBot, types
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

bot = TeleBot(...)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def get_filial(message: types.Message):
    markup_inline_branch = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='Tokio', callback_data='tokio'),
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='Texas', callback_data='texas'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Choose branch :", reply_markup=markup_inline_branch)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'tokio')
def get_tokio(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='Choose category', callback_data='category'),
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='Choose warehouse', callback_data='warehouse'))
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text="Choose category:", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'category')
def get_category(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='Milk', callback_data='milk'),
        InlineKeyboardButton(text='Electrocity', callback_data='electr'))
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text="Choose goods:", reply_markup=markup)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я забыла написать, сначала надо выбрать инлайн кнопка "Токио", после появляется кнопка "Категория" а после должен появится например кнопка "Milk",  у меня после нажатия "Категория" не появляется кнопка "Milk".

Comment: @Marina обновил, проверяйте

Comment: спасибо большое, хотела отметить,  но система не увеличивает Ваш рейтинг.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, как реализовать в этом проекте, кнопки "Вперед" И "Назад".
Спасибо.

Comment: @Marina просто дайте кнопке назад колбек предыдущего типа. А вообще это отдельный вопрос, так что и задавать его нужно отдельно

Comment: Вот здесь создала, тему.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461259/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%92%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%b8-%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8