# Как соединить кнопки "Вперед" и "Назад" в одной функции

Tags: python, telebot

Есть код, с кнопкой "Вперед" все понятно, но не могу в одной функции контролировать и кнопку ""Вперед" и "Назад". "Вперед" работает норм, но не могу реализовать кнопку "Назад".

Помогите пожалуйста с ответом.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:call.data=='category')
def get_category_1(call: types.CallbackQuery):

    markup_inline_category_1=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_oboy=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Обои', callback_data='oboy')
    item_vpered=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующий>>>", callback_data='vpered')
    markup_inline_category_1.add(item_oboi, vpered)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,text="Выбрать 
    категорию:",reply_markup=markup_inline_category_1)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:call.data=='vpered')   
def get_category_2(call: types.CallbackQuery): 

    markup_inline_category_2=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_travertin=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Эмульция', callback_data='travertin')
    item_vpered_2=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующий>>>", callback_data='vpered_2')
    item_nazad_2=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="<<<Назад", callback_data='nazad_2')
    markup_inline_category_2.add( item_travertin, item_nazad_2, item_vpered_2)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,text="Выбрать 
    категорию:",reply_markup=markup_inline_category_2)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:call.data=="vpered_2")  
def get_category_3(call: types.CallbackQuery): 
    
    markup_inline_category_3=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_akril=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Акрил', callback_data='akril')
    item_vpered_3=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующий>>>", callback_data='vpered_3')
    item_nazad_3=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="<<<Назад", callback_data='nazad_3')
    markup_inline_category_3.add( item_akril, item_vpered_3, item_nazad_3)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,text="Выбрать 
    категорию:",reply_markup=markup_inline_category_3)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:call.data=="vpered_3")   
def get_category_4(call: types.CallbackQuery):

    markup_inline_category_4=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_instrument=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Инструменты', callback_data='instrument')
    item_vpered_4=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующий>>>", callback_data='vpered_4')
    item_nazad_4=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="<<<Назад", callback_data='nazad_4')
    markup_inline_category_4.add( item_instrument, item_vpered_4, item_nazad_4)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,text="Выбрать 
    категорию:",reply_markup=markup_inline_category_4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажись вот так

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:call.data=='category')
def get_category_1(call: types.CallbackQuery):

    markup_inline_category_1=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_oboy=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Обои', callback_data='oboy')
    item_vpered=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующий>>>", callback_data='vpered')
    markup_inline_category_1.add(item_oboi, vpered)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,text="Выбрать категорию:",reply_markup=markup_inline_category_1)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:call.data=='vpered')   
def get_category_2(call: types.CallbackQuery): 

    markup_inline_category_2=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_travertin=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Эмульция', callback_data='travertin')
    item_vpered_2=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующий>>>", callback_data='vpered_2')
    item_nazad_2=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="<<<Назад", callback_data='category')
    markup_inline_category_2.add( item_travertin, item_nazad_2, item_vpered_2)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,text="Выбрать категорию:",reply_markup=markup_inline_category_2)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:call.data=="vpered_2")  
def get_category_3(call: types.CallbackQuery): 
    
    markup_inline_category_3=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_akril=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Акрил', callback_data='akril')
    item_vpered_3=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующий>>>", callback_data='vpered_3')
    item_nazad_3=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="<<<Назад", callback_data='vpered')
    markup_inline_category_3.add( item_akril, item_vpered_3, item_nazad_3)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,text="Выбрать категорию:",reply_markup=markup_inline_category_3)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:call.data=="vpered_3")   
def get_category_4(call: types.CallbackQuery):

    markup_inline_category_4=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_instrument=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Инструменты', callback_data='instrument')
    item_vpered_4=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Следующий>>>", callback_data='vpered_4')
    item_nazad_4=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="<<<Назад", callback_data='vpered_2')
    markup_inline_category_4.add( item_instrument, item_vpered_4, item_nazad_4)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,text="Выбрать категорию:",reply_markup=markup_inline_category_4)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.